# Due to online cache can't see website

Tags: untagged

Have uploaded a site after shifting the domain to new server. royaledecasa.com hosted on Windows. server is shifted today around 11am still niether site or mails are working.

On mobile can see the site but cant access webmail

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for including your domainname, that makes answering such things <strike>easier</strike> possible.

A quick check shows me:

```
www.royaledecasa.com.   86400   IN  A   50.22.12.12
```

Which has a DNS cache and therefore timeout of 86400 seconds, or 24 hours. That is how long it will take for cached DNS entries around the world to expire. Some will expire before others.

DNS changes will always require to time propagate and there's little you can do to force that.

You MX records appear to me as:

```
dig mx royaledecasa.com

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;royaledecasa.com.      IN  MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
royaledecasa.com.   86400   IN  MX  10 mail2.royaledecasa.com.
royaledecasa.com.   86400   IN  MX  21 mail2.royaledecasa.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
mail2.royaledecasa.com. 86400   IN  A   108.168.250.190
mail2.royaledecasa.com. 86400   IN  A   108.168.250.190
```

Since both primary and secondary MX record point to the same server you might as well delete one.
Or you may have made a typo there and your primary MX record should have been something like mail or mail1...